# PHP Curl POST with JSON returns Server Error 500 - Django

Tags: json, post, curl

I am using the code below to make PHP Curl POST request. Could someone tell me , why the server sends me Server Error Code 500? When open the api link in the browser and test it with json data everything is ok. I use the similar code to make PUT request and I don`t have problems.

```
            $postArray = array(
                "email" => $email
            );
            $json = json_encode( $postArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );

            $pl4m_url = "api-link";



            $ch = curl_init($pl4m_url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");  
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$json);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch); 
            echo $result;
```

Comment: `api-link` is actually being set?

Comment: @SunnyRGupta Yes its set :)